# How do I pass data to a component compiled through the use of $compile in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I would like to construct a single page app. When a user clicks on a particular object I would like to replace the current component on the page with another component. The code below is situated in a directive of a component and I am able to dynamically swap out whichever component I like. However when I swap my current component to `<detail></detail>` I would also like to pass some information to `<detail></detail>` so that it can manipulate this information in its controller and display this info within its template.

How would I go about doing something such as this?

```
var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.$ctrl.viewDetails = function() {
    $('#page-wrapper').html($compile('<detail></detail>')(scope));
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that there's no need to $compile here. It looks like the code falls into ['don't use Angular with jQuery' category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). Just combine `ng-if` with `ng-click` in directive template.

Answer (score 0):

You have typical anti-pattern. You should do it Angular way which is much simpler and straightforward: just use [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive. Something like this:

```html
<one ng-if="condition"></one>
<detail ng-if="!condition" data="$ctrl.someData"></detail>
```